# Run Simultaneous Functions for Patch Automation with PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, parallel-processing, automation, powershell-remoting

I've seen different post regarding paralleling or run functions simultaneously in parallel but the code in the answers have not quite worked for me. I'm doing patching automation and the functions I have all work and do their thing separately but since we work with more than 200+ computers, waiting for each function to finish with its batch of computers kind of defeats the purpose. I have the code in one script and in summary its structured like this:

## define global variables

$global:varN

## define sub-functions

function sub-function1()

function sub-functionN()

## define main functions

function InstallGoogleFunction($global:varN)
{

$var1

$result1 = sub-function1

$resultN = sub-functionN

}

function InstallVLCFunction($global:varN)
{

"similar code as above"

}

function InstallAppFunction($global:varN)
{

"similar code as above"

}

The functions will all install a different app/software and will write output to a file. The only thing is I cannot seem to run all the functions for installation without waiting for the first one to finish. I I tried start-job code but it executed and displayed a table like output but when verifying the computers neither had anything running on Task Manager. Is there a way powershell can run this installation functions at the same time? If I have to resort to a one-by-one I will call the functions by the least amount of time taken or the least computers the functions read they need to install I will but I just wanted someone to better explain if this can be done.

Comment: You mean to say that you want to install multiple software at the same time on same machine in parallel?

Comment: does your software installation needs rebooting target machine?

Comment: Install multiple software on multiple remote machines at the same time. No need to reboot any of them.

Comment: To run code on multiple remote machines in parallel, use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777). As an aside: if you're using global variables, not only is there no point in declaring them as _parameters_, it actually doesn't work.

Comment: I do use the Invoke-Command to remotely query or do stuff on the remote computers already and they work. The code is already working, for example if I test the GoogleChromeInstall function it goes though all the code (sub-routines, etc.) on each of the computers (one at a time) and this is fine, but if I want to run both GoogleChromeInstall and FirefoxInstall a the same time I would have to wait for the first function running to finish and so that the other function starts and then finishes.

Comment: I don't know if I worded the question correctly but basically all I want to do is to call all 7 installation functions simultaneously for them to do their thing without having to wait in like for the previous function to finish.... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading to achieve this. Below example shows how you can trigger tasks on multiple using multi threading in PowerShell.

Replace list of machines in `$Computers` with your machines and give it a try. Below example get the disk details on given machines

```
# This is your script you want to execute
$wmidiskblock = 
{ 
  Param($ComputerName = "LocalHost") 
  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class win32_logicaldisk |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} 
} 

# List of servers
$Computers = @("Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3")  

#Start all jobs in parallel 
ForEach($Computer in $Computers) 
{ 
   Write-Host $Computer 
   Start-Job -scriptblock $wmidiskblock  -ArgumentList $Computer 
} 

Get-Job | Wait-Job 

$out = Get-Job | Receive-Job 
$out |export-csv 'c:\temp\wmi.csv'
```

Comment: This will run code _locally_ in parallel (even though the code happens to be a `Get-WmiObject` call that targets a remote machine). I think the OP's intent is to run code _on remote machines_ in parallel. Also note that `Start-Job` uses _child processes_, not _threads_ (which is why it is quite slow); however, there is a thread-based `Start-ThreadJob` cmdlet available via the `ThreadJob` module (comes with PowerShell v6+, downloadable in older versions).